# Typo on Wooldridge book? (Econometric Analysis...)

Tags: conditional-expectation

i think there's a typo in the book "Econometric Analysis of cross section and panel data" from the author Jeffrey Wooldridge, in chapter 2, section 2.2.4 "Some Properties of Conditional Expectations":
[image]

I found a little confusing the fact that he's defining the functions $\mu_{1}()$ and $\mu_{2}()$, since they are the same!
I think that the last sentence should be:
"In other words, [.....], we can obtain $\mu_{2}(x)$ by computing the expected value of $\mu_{1}(w)$ given $x$: $\mu_{2}(x) = E[\mu_{1}(w) | x]$

Am i missing something? Mi intuition is that, in order to compute $E[y|x]$ one can first compute the expectation of y given w: Since we know w, we know x and the expectation of y given x would be easy to compute.
Any other insights about this would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct about the typo: It should be $\mu_2(\mathbf{x}) = E[\mu_1(\mathbf w)|\mathbf x]$ as you say. However it is not true in general that $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are the same. Note that here $\mathbf{w}$ and $\mathbf{x}$ are not ordinary variables; rather they are random vectors which may have different distributions from each other -- or more importantly, the distribution of $(y,\mathbf w)$ may be different from the distribution of $(y,\mathbf x)$. Also, $\mathbf{w}$ could be a random vector on $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbf{x}$ a random vector on $\mathbb R^m$, with $m$ not necessarily equal to $n$. In this case $\mu_1$ has domain $\mathbb R^m$, while $\mu_2$ has domain $\mathbb R^n$, so in this case they could not possibly be the same.

The equation $\mu_2(\mathbf{x}) = E[\mu_1(\mathbf w)|\mathbf x]$ in principle provides a way to find $E[y | \mathbf x]$ in terms of $E[y | \mathbf w]$, but whether this is easy to compute or not depends on the specific situation.